# Find the greatest value of $a^2\cdot b^3$ where $a+b=10$

Tags: inequality, optimization

Find the greatest value of $a^2\cdot b^3$ where $a,b$ are positive real numbers satisfying $a+b=10$. Determine the values of $a,b$ for which the greatest value is attained.

At first I tried to find the value by putting $a=10-b$, I found a expression, but I got not way to do anything.

If we apply A.M-G.M. inequality, I think we found the minimum value or something else. It is a pre-Olympiad level problem. So I need some answers or some good hints.

Comment: What goes wrong when you substitute $a=10-b$?  Seems like a simple matter of differentiation.

Comment: $a^2 \cdot b^3 = (10-b)^2 \cdot b^3$... then differentiate with respect to $b$...

Comment: As an alternative, you could just use Lagrange multipliers...but really, straight forward differentiation works fine.

Answer (score 6):

The Am-GM inequality says that $\{a_n\}$ are given then $\frac {\sum a_n}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{\prod a_n}$.

Rewrite $a+b = 10$ as $2 \times \frac a2 + 3 \times \frac b3 = 10$. Now, apply AM-GM and see what happens, noting that equality occurs when $\frac a2 = \frac b3$.

Applying AM-GM with the set $\{\frac a2,\frac a2,\frac b3,\frac b3,\frac b3\}$, we get:
$$
\frac{\frac a2+\frac a2+\frac b3+\frac b3+\frac b3}{5} \geq \sqrt[5]{\frac a2\cdot\frac a2\cdot\frac b3\cdot\frac b3\cdot\frac b3}
$$

Simplifying, we get that $\frac{a+b}{5} \geq \sqrt[5]{\frac {a^2b^3}{2^23^3}}$.

Knowing that $a+b=10$ gives us:
$$
2 \geq \sqrt[5]{\frac {a^2b^3}{2^23^3}}
$$
Taking the fifth power of both sides:
$$32 \times 2^23^3 \geq a^2b^3$$
which equates to $a^2b^3 \leq 3456$. This is attained when $3a = 2b$ i.e. $a=4,b=6$.

You can also differentiate, but then I believe this is not allowed in Olympiad exams.

Comment: @ac... Please briefly explain you answer.

Comment: @SufaidSaleel I have expanded little bit. If you still don't understand then this time point out what you don't understand (which step, while line etc.)

Comment: It leads to answer very quickly! $(+1)$

Comment: @Amirali Thank you. It contrasts very much with the other answers on this page, as I realize now, about 4.5 years after writing the answer!

Comment: Yes, old but gold !

Comment: @Amirali Old is truly gold , as I realize after this answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have to maximize $(10-b)^2b^3$.
Expand, differentiate, and get $5 b^2 (b^2 - 16 b + 60)=0$.
Therefore, $b=0, 6, 10$. Now test each of these in turn.

We need $a,b \ge 0$ and so $0 \le b \le 10$.
Since $(10-b)^2b^3 \ge 0$ in this interval, the maximum point must be  $b=6$.

Answer (score 1):

With the given condition you have to find maximum of $(10-b)^2b^3$.

If you differentiate it with respect to $b$ and equate it to zero. You will get maxima (an easy check on double differentiation will verify it). It will give you $b=0,6,10$. You can easily go further now.

Answer (score 1):

*Just to give an answer using Lagange multipliers.*

Consider $$F=a^2\ b^3+\lambda(a+b-10)$$ COmpute the partial derivatives and set them equal to zero. So $$F'_a=2ab^3+\lambda=0\tag 1$$ $$F'_b=3a^2b^2+\lambda=0\tag 2$$ $$F'_\lambda=a+b-10=0\tag 3$$ Considering $(1)$ and $(2)$, we then have $$2ab^3=3a^2b^2\implies ab^2(2b-3a)=0$$ Then the possible solutions $a=0$ or $b=0$ (both of them would give $a^2b^3=0$) or $b=\frac {3a}2$. Replacing in $F'_\lambda$ then gives $a=4$ and then $b=6$ and then $a^2b^3=3456$.

If the problem was instead $a+b=x$, the solution would have been $a=\frac{2x}5$, $b=\frac{3x}5$, $a^2b^3=\frac{108 x^5}{3125}$.